# Docker Compose - metricbeat cointainer stop after run compose commands

Tags: docker, docker-compose, command, metricbeat

Hello here my docker compose.yml the command will execute but after the container will stop.
I am tring to use command and entrypoint but the result is the same.

```
metricbeat:
 build: .
 command: metricbeat modules enable docker
 image: docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat-oss:7.12.1
 user: root
 environment:
  - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=opensearch-node1:9200
  - KIBANA_HOST=opensearch-dashboards:5601
  - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=admin
  - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=admin
 volumes:
  - metricbeat-data01:/usr/share/metricbeat/data
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
 networks:
  - opensearch-net
 links:
  - opensearch-node1
 depends_on:
  - opensearch-node1
 volumes:
  opensearch-data1:
  metricbeat-data01:
 networks:
  opensearch-net:`
```

---

**docker composer up**

```
opensearch-node1| Disabling execution of_configuration.sh for 
OpenSearch Security Plugin
opensearch-node1| Disabling OpenSearch Security Plugin
metricbeat_1 | Enabled docker
docker_metricbeat_1 exited with code 0 `
```

by using docker exec will work, but I will do in composer file:

```
docker exec -ti <container_name> sh -c "metricbeat modulesenable docker && curl -XPOST -H 'osd-xsrf: true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://opensearch-dashboards:5601/api/opensearch-dashboards/dashboards/import?exclude=index-pattern&force=true' -d@/usr/share/metricbeat/kibana/7/dashboard/Metricbeat-docker-overview.json"
```

Comment: `command: metricbeat modules enable docker` - probably it executes this one and exits with code 0

Comment: how can not do it?

Comment: Here you can find the information about running metricbeat container: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/running-on-docker.html